# what is the reason of "zero"

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using now JCreator. I don't get this right; What is the reason of setting automatically "zero" values in out-of-use array elements? Is this something like an optimization of the compiler or arising from JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in [JLS Section 15.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html), and I quote

> Then, if a single DimExpr appears, a single-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value

where the default values for primitive types (that are class variables, instance variables, or array components) are documented in [JLS Section 4.5.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#96595), which is 0 for the numeric primitives, `false` for booleans, and `null` for reference types.

Answer (score 6):

It's impossible for an array element *not* to have a value, so one had to be chosen, and for numerical types, zero is the obvious default.

More concretely: what do you think should be returned when an "out-of-use" array position is read?

Comment: Then, we should have ponder upon toString() method :)

Comment: @EbeninAmi - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, we ought not to judge toString method, It gives you the default representation value unless you customize

Comment: @Ebenin Ami: I still don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I made an anology between out-of-use array position non-customized toString() method. Thats all

Answer (score 1):

Out of use array elements are not used, so the value they contain should not matter. Whats important is that when you instantiate a new array (of ints), all its elements are initialized to 0. This is just easier to use and safer than if they were initialized to an arbitrary value, because most of the time, when you create an array, either you explicitely initialize every element and the default value doesn't matter, or you don't because you all want them to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Java array is an object. When you create an array (i.e allocate memory for ) of primitive types then it will create `n` elements or variables with their default value. But in case of `reference` (non-primitive) types it will create `n` elements (reference variables) of that type whose initial value will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a holdover from the days of C. If you were an poor tired developer debugging a one million line program, would you rather inspect an array and wonder wether you had put those mystery values in it, or have a greater assurance that the array had not been populated because it had 'default values' in it?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get this right; What is the reason of setting automatically "zero" values in out-of-use array elements?

It is part of the Java language specification.  The Java designers took the view that it was better that array elements that are not explicitly initialized (by the program) still start out with a predictable value.  The reason that it is better is that it makes programs behave more predictably.

The choice of zero is somewhat arbitrary, but zero does strike me as an obvious choice.

(Note that for arrays of objects, any value other than `null` would be *interpreted* as a reference for some object.  The chance of a random uninitialized word of memory pointing to a valid object at all (let alone, one of the right type) is pretty small.  And if it doesn't, you've just toasted Java type-safety.)

> Is this something like an optimization of the compiler or arising from JVM?

I doubt that was the main reason.  I guess in theory there could be special hardware support for initializing large regions of memory (or virtual memory) to zeros.

Comment: zeroing on Sparc is extra optimized

Comment: @bestsss - yea, but as I said, I doubt that was the **main reason** they chose zero rather than some value as the default value.

Comment: AFAIK quick zeroing was added to improve java performance (not other way around). the comment is just stating such hardware is available. other than that zeroing is needed for security reasons (even more than predictability) and to enforce non invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed no one mentioned the most important part of zeroing - security and integrity considerations.

Java by design is secure and under normal circumstances java code may not crash the process or (worse) perform an illegal operation like read/writing the filesystem w/o granted permissions.

Lack of an arbitrary filling during object/array creation may leave stale references to secure data even for primitives `like int/byte/long`. References are absolutely necessary to be in valid state at any time and the only truly valid state implicitly available is `null`.

Zeroing has other very important benefits like perfect predictability and can be carried during garbage collection asynchronously - no allocation cost.